# C# equivalent of this C++ code

Tags: c#, visual-c++, activex

Is there any C# equivalent of the code below?

```
 HRESULT hr;
    ActiveXSite* pSite;
    pSite = CAxWindowlessHost<CMainDlg>::CreateControlSite(L"AgControl.AgControl", NULL, IDC_AGCONTROL1);
    if ( pSite != NULL )
    {
        // disable right-click!
        pSite->SetAllowRClick(false);
        // set moniker URL
        CComBSTR bstrUrl("file:///C:/Temp/SilverlightDemo.xap");
        pSite->SetUrl(bstrUrl);

        PropertyParams props;
        props.push_back( PropertyParam(L"Windowless", L"true") );
        props.push_back( PropertyParam(L"MinRuntimeVersion", L"2.0.31005.0") );
        props.push_back( PropertyParam(L"Source", static_cast<LPCWSTR>(bstrUrl)) );
        props.push_back( PropertyParam(L"InitParams", L"") );
        hr = pSite->ActivateAx(rc, false, props);
    }
```

Comment: Just added tags "activex" and "c#".

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to embed a silverlight application into your own desktop application. I didn't do it myself, but it seems somewhat related to

[Host silverlight in the Windows.Forms...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851681/host-silverlight-in-the-windows-forms-without-the-webbrowser-control)

Also try googling for "embedding silverlight in winforms". One possibility would be to embed a web-browser control and load the silverlight app into it.

PS: There is certainly no direct equivalent of your code since ATL is a C++-technology ...

Comment: >>t seems that you want to embed a silverlight application into your own desktop application

I tried to host AgControl from COM component in winform but it's not working for some reasons. But Windows Media Player is working fine. Strange.

Comment: dont want to use SL2 OOB and Web Browser. I'm checking  ISilverlightViewer,  IXcpControlHost and IXcpControlHost2 interfaces. My C++ knowledge is so limited. :(

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the rather perverse approach of trying to make a line for line transcription using P/Invoke, the expected way of using native COM objects from .net is via the [Runtime Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)